# What is the failure mode for a power supply being incorrectly set for 110/240v using the switch?

Tags: power-supply, failure

A recent [post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tifu/comments/4hng54/tifu_flicking_the_red_switch_on_pc/) recounted the story of where someone fried a power supply by flicking the little red switch on the back that switches between 110v and 240v modes.

[image: Back of a power supply for a PC]

(The thing between the receptacles)

The story involves loud bangs, sparks, and smoke when toggling that switch.

- Why does setting this switch incorrectly result in such a dramatic physical reaction?
- What is actually happening to the components in the supply when this is set incorrectly?

Comment: Very poor design. You should have to use a tool to change that switch.

Comment: @EJP That could/would cause issues when people move areas - particularly in parts of Asia, I believe it's pretty easy to find a mix of 115 and 230. Using a full-range PSU is a much better idea.

Comment: Anecdotally, when I accidentally plugged one of these set to 110 in a 220 outlet, the result was a meter-long flame leaving through the fan hole, and a pretty nice short-circuit causing the cable to almost melt in 2 seconds. If one pays attention to my living room wall it is still a little bit pale where the char mark was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch changes the power supply configuration from a full-wave bridge (open) rectifier to a voltage doubler (closed). The main DC supply rail is normally ~300VDC when the switch is in the proper position for the supply voltage.

Doubler (120VAC) - the output is peak \$2\cdot 120 \sqrt{2} \$ = 339V

Full wave (230VAC)- the output is peak \$230 \sqrt{2} \$ = 325V

Average will be a bit lower than the peak.

(Component designations refer to the partial schematic below). If you have it plugged into 230V and switched to the 120V setting (SPST switch S1 is closed) it will attempt to create about a 600V+ rail, which will kill the main switching transistors (Q1 and Q2) and possibly the main capacitors and other parts if the fuse does not blow fast enough. The transistors will fail shorted and short the main bus, causing high current to flow, blowing the fuse with a pop.

Each main filter capacitor C5 and C6 is rated at (typically) 200VDC and they are connected in series, so 400V is the maximum.

Typical schematic (partial) of such a supply from [here](http://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/compaq-power-supply-200w.jpg):

[image]